# Lex semi-complex regex expression

Tags: regex, lex

So, I'm working on a project for school where we have to make a shell and I've been doing fine until now. I need to figure out how I can extend my regular expression for "words" so that special characters are recognized.

Basically, I need to be able to separate words by certain special characters, but not if they're escaped.

For example: `echo sometext>file.txt` would be tokenized as `WORD WORD GREAT WORD`. However, `echo sometext\>file.txt` would be tokenized as `WORD WORD`, where "sometext>file.txt" is all one word.

I'm having trouble figuring out a regular expression that can handle this. Here's what I have currently:
`[^ \t\n][^ \t\n<>&|]*`. This works for picking out the things like `echo sometext>file.txt` but I'm not sure how I can extend it to look for any character except whitespace or a special character, unless that special character is escaped.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.  Can you show us clear input and output data?

Comment: It would also be helpful to specify what regular expression engine you're using, since they all have subtly different behaviours. Are you using (f)lex to generate a lexical analyser, as possibly indicated by [tag:lex]?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have been more explicit. I am using lex to tokenize the input, then yacc to create a grammatical structure for these tokens. The token `WORD` is used for pretty much anything that isn't a special operator (<, >, &, |). These words are then formed into the commands that needed to be run. The case I'm looking at here is where one of these special operators is connected to an argument for the previous command. I need my regex to be able to cut off when it encounters one of these operators, unless the operator is escaped (preceded by a backslash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
(?:\\.|[^ \t\n<>&|])*
```

This "breaks word" on  , `\t`, `\n`, `<`, `>`, `&` and `|` (i.e. what is in `[^ \t\n<>&|]`), except if escaped.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/lEkNRk/1

### Or:

```
(?:\\.|[^ \t\n<>&|])+|[ \t\n<>&|]
```

This also matches, individually,  , `>` and so on, **if not escaped**. Maybe it is better suitable for your suggested `WORD WORD GREAT WORD` pattern.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/rkh8lC/1

Comment: I do still need to include the escaped character in the word, so the noncapturing group isn't necessary, but I believe I've gotten it working with the `(\\.|[^ \t\n<>&|])+` (changed the * to a + because the word needs to be at least one character long).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using (f)lex, you'll probably want something like this. It's based on the grammar summary in [Posix 2016](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10_02), with a couple of bashisms thrown in for fun, and I tried to use the same token names as that document.

There are many important features omitted here:

- Correctly handling quotes requires a lot more work. I didn't even try it. (The most annoying part is that you can include a command expansion `$(...)` inside a quoted string, which is an independent lexical context.)
- I didn't include the code which would save a copy of `yytext` into `yylval`, which needs to be done for `WORD` and also for the reserved words (but not the metacharacters or symbols starting with a metacharacter) because reserved words are not always reserved. This fact creates some issues in the grammar as well.
- I didn't distinguish between `NAME` and `WORD` (rules 5 and 8).
- I didn't bother to recognize `IO_NUMBER`, although it is quite straight-forward using (f)lex's trailing-context operator. (Numbers are only special if the character immediately following the number is `<` or `>`.
- I also didn't attempt to recognize `ASSIGNMENT_WORD` (see 2.10.1). Assignments are not really syntactically significant, but they are semantically significant and it is useful to set a flag when such words are recognised. A pattern to recognise `ASSIGNMENT_WORD`s and set a flag in `yylval` could be added before the `WORD` pattern (see the note on ordering patterns, below).

There is a note on the ordering of these patterns below. The fact that (f)lex has a defined matching order when multiple patterns match the same token often considerably simplifies the construction of regular expressions, but it also means that in some cases rules have to be carefully ordered.

```
[|&;()<>\n]   return *yytext;   /* Metacharacters, including newline */
[[:space:]]   ;                 /* Ignore other whitespace */
"||"          return OR_IF;     /* Multi-metacharacter sequences */
"&&"          return AND_IF;
";;"          return DSEMI;
"<<"          return DLESS;
"<<-"         return DLESSDASH;
"<<<"         return TLESS;     /* Bash here strings */
">>"          return DGREAT;
"<&"          return LESSAND;
">&"          return GREATAND;
"<>"          return LESSGREAT;
">|"          return CLOBBER;

"(("          return DLparen;   /* Bash arithmetic conditional */
"))"          return DRparen;

"if"          return If;        /* reserved words, only matched when   */
"then"        return Then;      /* they are a complete word (and often */
"else"        return Else;      /* treated as regular words even then).*/
"elif"        return Elif;
"fi"          return Fi;
"do"          return Do;
"done"        return Done;
"case"        return Case;
"esac"        return Esac;
"while"       return While;
"until"       return Until;
"for"         return For;
"in"          return In;
"time"        return Time;      /* In bash, this is reserved */

"{"           return Rbrace;
"}"           return Lbrace;
"!"           return Bang;

"[["          return DLbracket; /* Bash conditional */
"]]"          return DRbracket;

"#".*         ;                 /* Comments. Only if # would start a word. */

([^[:space:]|&;()<>]|\\.)+ return WORD;
```

This collection of patterns is carefully ordered so that the correct token will be produced; the patterns are not mutually exclusive. In particular:

- A new line character will match both of the first two rules. Since it is actually syntactically significant, the ignore rule is placed second.
- Metacharacters are never part of a token (unless escaped), so the `WORD` rule doesn't allow them. On the other hand, `{`, `}` and `!` are not metacharacters, although they have grammatical significance in some contexts; they must first be recognised as words in order to be used. In this sense, they are similar to keywords like `if` and `for`; their patterns need to come before the `WORD` rule so that they are correctly identified when they form a complete word.
- Similarly, the `#` character only starts a comment when it is the first character in a word. Otherwise, it is an ordinary word character. Again, recognising (and ignoring) comments requires the matching rule to come before `WORD`. Note that the rule does *not* match the newline which terminates the comment; that newline is actually syntactically significant, like any other newline, and so it must be returned to the parser.

Comment: I actually do have a lot of this in my lex file already, which I should have mentioned. I was just looking for a way to make lex stop the `WORD` when it encounters a special character, unless the character is escaped. I did end up using something very similar to what you recommended for the `WORD`. I have already dealt with subcommands inside the $( ) and it was quite a pain. Luckily, the project doesn't require us to be able to recognize one of these inside a quoted string.

Comment: @andrew: the real bash parser is a nightmare of special cases. Effectively, to handle command expansion, you need to be able to recursively invoke the lexer (and parser); the simplest (or least complicated) solution is to use a push-parser, but that bison feature is much more revent than bash.